# Xpedition Designer DNP (no fit) components

Tags: schematics, cad, siemens, dxdesigner

Could somebody please let me know what the method is to mark a component as DNP (not to be fitted in production) in Xpedition Designer (schematic entry).  I can't find it in the docs and I'm used to using Altium with its "Variant" system.
cheers